# Doom Emacs: Key binding SPC-SPC for easy file navigation

Tags: emacs, key-bindings

For a couple of days, I've been trying to bind `SPC SPC` (now `find-file` or `project-find-file`) to a bottom popup that would display easy navigation to my files.

**Possible solution - method 1 (modifying the below code snippet):**

Here's the simple popup code (works perfectly and gets activated upon `SPC e`)

```lisp
    (map! :leader
          (:prefix ("e" . "open config files")
           :desc "alacritty.yml" "a" #'(lambda () (interactive) (find-file "~/.config/alacritty/alacritty.yml"))
           :desc "nvim" "n" #'(lambda () (interactive) (find-file "~/.config/nvim/init.vim"))
           :desc "polybar" "p" #'(lambda () (interactive) (find-file "~/.config/polybar/config")))
```

But I'd like to use `SPC SPC` instead of `SPC e`. When I change `:prefix` from `e` to `SPC`, I get this error:

```
Key sequence SPC starts with non-prefix key SPC.
```

How can I bind `SPC SPC` to a similar navigation (i.e. the above "open config files" menu activated with "SPC e"?

**Possible solution - method 2 (creating custom function):**

I suspect that what I want could also be done by the (custom) functioin. I managed to get `SPC SPC` to invoke `my-own-nav-function` (see the code below), but I could not make it work.
This is how I trigger the function (upon hitting "SPC SPC", the code triggers my-own-nav-function as expected):

```lisp
    (map! :leader
          :desc "navigation function" "SPC" #'my-own-nav-function)
```

The function that I tried to create is this:

```
(defun my-own-nav-function ()
(interactive)
:desc "alacritty.yml" "a" #'(lambda () (interactive) (find-file "~/.config/alacritty/alacritty.yml"))
:desc "nvim" "n" #'(lambda () (interactive) (find-file "~/.config/nvim/init.vim"))
:desc "polybar" "p" #'(lambda () (interactive) (find-file "~/.config/polybar/config")))
```

I can navigate to this function via M-x and execute it, but it doesn't seem to be doing anything. If I could get that function work, it would solve my problem.

---

Note: I'm running Doom Emacs on Linux (GNU Emacs 27.2)

Comment: You changed your question in the middle of it, saying that you solved your initial problem and now you have another. Only one question per post, please. If you want to pose only your initial question, about key binding, and you want to answer it, then do that (and remove the rest). If you think that Q & A won't be useful to others, then you might consider deleting the question instead. You can also pose your second question, about defining a function, separately.

Comment: Hi there, thank you for the response. I haven't solved my problem. Ideally, I would like to get the code working without creating any function. I am stuck with the function that would be able to achieve the same result anyways. I hope that makes sense? My problem is this: I would like to hit SPC-SPC and get taken to easy navigation to my files. Maybe I don't even need my own custom function, which would be great, but I wasn't able to get that code working yet.

Comment: Please put any relevant info in your question, not just in comments. Comments can be deleted at any time. And make your question post ask only one, clear, specific question.

Comment: Hi Drew, I have reformulated it now and try to make it as easy to understand as possible. Please let me know. Many thanks